# Error in query when trying to Import Excel file to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures

I got this code from `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686` , and i did the example , and i am trying to create a Stored Procedure :

```
use [Libatel]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Import1]

AS
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO CardsImported FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\Barcode.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Sheet1$]

END
GO
```

but i can't create it , i got this error :

```
"Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Import1, Line 6>OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Found the way ! well i have a 64 bit PC , i uninstalled my 32 bit office that came with the PC , i got the 64 bit version , i downloaded "AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 , that's pretty much it

Comment: You don't didn't need to uninstall the 32-bit office if you install the x64 with /passive as noted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032222/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries